# fastlane match generate new certificate with push notifications enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, fastlane, fastlane-match

I'm a bit confused on how I'm supposed to add push notification capabilities to an app where I have generated provisioning profiles/certs using `fastlane match`

I'm trying to run my device in development after enabling and setting up push notifications but keep seeing the error that the capabilities are not supported by the development provisioning profile that `match` generated for me

I have tried a number of times to nuke the development cert and generating a new one but it continues to create a certification without push notification capabilities enabled

What is the process I am supposed to go through to add push notifications and generate a new provisioning profile/certificate with push notification capabilities?

Comment: Adding app capabilities(like: push notification) is done through Xcode or the developer portal. Take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding_capabilities_to_your_app. After enabling or disabling capabilities you need to run Match again to update the profiles and certificates.I don't think there is need to nuke them, just rerun Match it should see the profiles got updated with the new capabilities.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue!

You need to *also* add the capability to the app identifier via the [apple developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/#/overview/). Once the capability is added to your app's identifier, `match` will generate provisioning profiles with the correct capabilities.

From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/registering_your_app_with_apns):

> Important
>
> In your developer account, also enable the push notification
> service for the App ID assigned to your project. For more information
> about configuring your developer account, go to your [Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/account/#/overview/)
> page.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to go and delete the existing provisioning profile managed by match from the developer portal. Then, it re-created the correct provisioning profile and everything is good now.